# Term and Conditions Not working error "Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order" before placing order magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, terms-and-conditions

**Term and Conditions** Not working error message "Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order" before placing order magento 2.2.2 custom theme.If anyone have faced this type issue please guide me,thanks.